# How to get data about category in category.php

Tags: categories, theme-development, themes, terms

I have to make custom `category.php` template, but how do I get data about category in `category.php`?
I need these:

- Category name and id
- Category's parent name and id
- All category's items

Let's say our link is www.website.com/category/sub-category and what we want is to display category and sub-category fullname + all sub-category items.

Comment: Just make it! And then share some custom code you've made and we'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so there are many ways to solve this. You can use special template tags for some of these (for example `the_archive_title` to show the title of current category, and so on).

But to achieve all of these, you'll need to get [`get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).

If you're viewing category, this function will return current category object.

So after:

```
$current_cat = get_queried_object();
```

You can get its name using:

```
echo $current_cat->name;
```

And its id using:

```
echo $current_cat->term_id;
```

To get its parent:

```
if ( $current_car->parent ) {
    $parent = get_category( $current_car->parent ); 
    echo $parent->name;
    echo $parent->term_id;
}
```

And to get all subcategories of `$parent`:

```
$categories = get_categories( array('parent' => $parent->term_id) );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo $category->name;
}
```